# Differentiate $e^{9x}/(-8x^5-4x)$

Tags: derivatives

I have used the quotient rule to differentiate the expression, but I'm not sure how to simplify from here:

$$\frac{  (9e^{9x})*(-8x^5-4x) - (e^{9x}*-40x^4-4) }{(-8x^5-4x)^2}$$

Comment: You need to clean up your parentheses so that the Order of Operations is more clear.

Comment: Also, the derivative of $9e^{9x}$ is $81e^{9x}$, not $9e^{9x}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{  (9e^{9x})*(-8x^5-4x) - (e^{9x}*-40x^4-4) }{(-8x^5-4x)^2}$$
Pay attention to your parentheses
$$\frac{  (9e^{9x})*(-8x^5-4x) - e^{9x}*(-40x^4-4) }{(-8x^5-4x)^2}$$
$$\frac{  (9e^{9x})*(-2x^5-x) - e^{9x}*(-10x^4-1) }{(4x^5+2x)^2}$$
$$\frac{  e^{9x}(-18x^5+10x^4-9x+1) }{4x^2(2x^4+1)^2}$$

Comment: Can you just divide one expression with 2 and the other one with 4?

Comment: oh @maria at the denominator you have an exponent 2 so $2^2=4$ thats why

Comment: I don't understand how the $(9e^{9x})$ disappear?

Comment: It didnt disapear it's still there since i multiplied by a factor 9 what was inside the parentheses... @Maria  Example you can do this $$9e^{9x}(x-2)=e^{9x}(9x-18)$$

Answer (score 0):

After getting to the following result by doing some math:

$$\frac{  e^{9x}(-18x^5+10x^4-9x+1) }{(4x^5+2x)^2}= \frac{  e^{9x}(-18x^5+10x^4-9x+1)} {16x^{10}+16x^6+4x^2}$$

you can perform long division of the polynomial of the denominator by the polynomial of the denominator. And this is a much more simplified from.

Comment: I don't understand how the $(9e^{9x})$ disappear?

Comment: $e^x$ is the common factor and you factorize.

Comment: Oh okey but when I factorize I get: $ e^{9x}(9*-8x^5-4x+40x^4+4) $

Comment: It's $e^{9x}(9*(-8x^5-4x)+40x^4+4) $ which extends to what I wrote.